# JS does not work if i remove alert statement

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, d3.js

I am building a Treemap layout using d3.js and facing a typical problem with the code. The code works if an alert statement is put other wise it doesn't.  I am briefly explaining code below,

default.HTML file and FetchData.java

1. A form tag with 3 radio buttons and 2 text boxes. (The text boxes will be used as a date filter for fetching the DB data)
2. A button with onclick event that will call the function loadNewData().
3. loadNewData -It does a AJAX call to a servlet "FetchData.java" with query parameters as inputs from the text boxes
4. The "FetchData.java" connects to DB (each time on onclick event),  extracts the data and write it into a file called "OuputJSON" . The random number is generated everytime for every onclick event.
5. This file name  is sent back to the AJAX call (process function in default.html) is an input to another JS function call called wrapperFunc(str)
6. This function calls the d3.json that takes the filename (URL of the json data file) and creates a treemap.

Step 6 works properly i put an alert statement just before calling the wrapperFunc(str). So there will not be any issue with d3.sjon function. As I remove the alert it doesn't work.
Any help is much appreciated

```
    <!-- DEFAULT.HTML -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
            <script type="text/javaScript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
            <script>
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                function loadNewData(){
                    //alert("AJAX CALL");                
                    xhr.open("GET","FetchData?from="+document.getElementById("from").value+"&to="+document.getElementById("to").value,true);
                    //xhr.open("GET","FetchData",false);
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=process;
                    xhr.send(null);
                }
                function process(){
                    //alert("proces()");
                    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                        str = xhr.responseText;
                        //alert(str);
                        wrapperFunc(str);
                    }                
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
             <form>
                    <label><input  type="radio" name="mode" value="size" checked> Clicks</label>    
            <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="ctr"> Ctr</label> 
            <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="searches"> Searches</label> 
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label>From</label>
                    <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
                    <label>to</label>
                    <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
                    <input type="button" id="bt1" value="fetch" onclick="loadNewData()">                
             </form>             
            <script>

                function wrapperFunc(str){                  
                        // D3 CODE HERE
                               var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
            width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var color = d3.scale.category20();
            var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
                                    .size([width, height])
                                    .sticky(true)
                                    .value(function(d) { return d.clicks;});    

            var svg = d3.select("body")         
                                .append("svg")
                                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right )
                                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                                .append("g");

    d3.json('data/'+str,function(error,root){
       if (error) {
            console.log("Inside Error");
            console.log(error); 
                          } else {
            console.log("Inside root");
            console.log(root); 
                          }

    var rects = svg.datum(root)
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(treemap.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .call(position);

    var texts = svg.selectAll("text") 
            .data(treemap.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .call(textPrint);

    //Tooltip and highlighting starts
    d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover",mouseover); 
    d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseout",mouseout); 
    //Tooltip and Highlighting ends

    //Transition of the Treemap.
    d3.selectAll("input").on("change",change);                          

    function change(){

        var value = this.value;
        if (this.value === "ctr") { value =  function(d) {return d.ctr;}}
        else if (this.value === "searches") { value = function(d) {return d.searches;}}
        else { value = function(d) {return d.clicks;}}    
        //alert(value);
        rects
            .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
            .transition()           
            .duration(1500)
            .call(position);    

        texts
            .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
            .transition()
            .delay(1500)
            .duration(500)
            .call(textPrint);
        }//change

 });//d3.json



function position(){
        this.attr("x", function(d) {return d.x;})
            .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y;})
    .attr("width", function(d) {return d.dx;})
    .attr("height", function(d) {return d.dy;})
    .attr("stroke","white")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {   
                if(d.children == null)
                 return color(d.parent.sub_group); // color(d.parent.name);
                            else
                 return null;                       
                                });
                       }

function textPrint(){
    this.attr("x",function(d) {return d.x + 3;})
    .attr("y",function(d) {return d.y + 10;})
    .attr("class","node")                   
    .text(function(d){
            if(d.dx <= 10 || d.dy <= 10){ return ""; } //If the rect is too small do not display the text
                else if (d.children == null){
                    var pxK = 6.6,txtLngth = (d.clientid).length,txtAccomadate = Math.round(d.dx/pxK);
                    if (txtAccomadate >= txtLngth)                                      
                        return d.clientid;                              
                    else 
                                                return "";
                // return (d.clientid).substr(0,txtAccomadate);
                            }
                            else
                    return null;
                            });
         }

function mouseover(d){ 

    // The below code is used for highlighting the element (i.e. rect) on mouse hover 
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill", "orange");

    //Get this rects x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + (d.dx)/2;
    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + (d.dy)/2;

    //Update the tooltip position and value
    d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")
    .select("#value")
    .text(d.parent.sub_group+"--"+d.clientid);

    //Show the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);         

}

function mouseout(d) {    

    d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
    if(d.children == null)
        return color(d.parent.sub_group);
    else
        return null;                        
    })          
    //Hide the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);      
}

                }//wrapperFunc                  
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

FetchData.java - is a servlet that extracts the data

```
    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import com.aol.poc.d3js.dbConnect.NetezzaJdbcConnection;
    import com.aol.poc.d3js.properties.*;
    import com.aol.poc.d3js.treemap.CsvToJson_V2;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    /**
     *
     * @author M1025322
     */
    @WebServlet(name = "FetchData", urlPatterns = {"/FetchData"})
    public class FetchData extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {       

            String from="",to="",filetod3="";
            from = request.getParameter("from");
            to = request.getParameter("to");    

            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.getWriter().write(generateJSONDataFile(from,to));
            response.getWriter().flush();
        }        

        public String generateJSONDataFile(String from,String to){
            NetezzaJdbcConnection njc = new NetezzaJdbcConnection();
            CsvToJson_V2 readCsv = new CsvToJson_V2();

            if(from == null || to == null){
                System.out.println("Inside if null");
               njc.extractData();
            }            
            else{
                System.out.println("Inside else");
                njc.extractData(from,to);
            }            
               String filetod3 = readCsv.readCsv();    

               return filetod3;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: clear the browser cache and try again

Comment: Which browser you are using

Comment: Doesnt work with clearing the browser cache. I do a synchronous AJAX call and it works only with alert statement.`open("get",url,"FALSE")`. Anything else u can suggest....

Comment: I am using IE, but tried with chrome and firefox also. It gave me the same problem

Comment: I don't see any calls to `d3.json` in your code.

Comment: I have not added it here. Inside the wrapper function `d3.json('data/'+str,function(error,root){ //treepmap creation }` . I don't think the problem is with that.

Comment: I have added the d3 code also now. Please help.

Comment: It may be caused by a race condition. The `d3.json` might be being invoked before the JSON file is created, the `alert` dialog stops the execution until the user clicks 'Ok', giving more time to the backend to generate the file. Try adding a pause instead of the alert dialog, or loading an existing file instead of a generated one to see if the visualization works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally understood the problem i was facing. `d3.json(url,callback)` itself does an AJAX call. When I recieved the filename (JSON data) from the servlet and passed it to d3.json function it was doing another call to the server to fetch the file. Since it was async, the code d3 code gets executed and the data was not recieved. I understood this issue when the below statement threw error (object XMLHttpRequest) instead of json object ([Object Object])
                `if (error) {
                console.log(error); 
                } else {
                console.log(root);`

So I decided to remove the d3.json function and pass a complete JSON string from the file and using the JS `eval()` function convert it into JSON object and run the d3 code. This worked and i need not have to any alert statement issue anymore. I am pasting the imporatant parts of the code below. Please note that the css code is not here and the servlet code is same as above except the difference that `return filetod3;` will retun the JSON data instead of JSON file name. The CSS file i have not put here.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">     
            <script type="text/javaScript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/mystyle.css">        
            <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",      
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                }
                });
                $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",      
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                }
                });

            });
            function openModal() {        
                document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
            }

            function closeModal() {
                document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';
            }
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                function loadNewData(){
                    openModal();
                    //alert("AJAX CALL");  
                    xhr.open("GET","FetchData?from="+document.getElementById("from").value+"&to="+document.getElementById("to").value,true);
                    //xhr.open("GET","FetchData",false);
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=process;
                    xhr.send(null);
                }
                function process(){
                    //alert("proces()");
                     if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                       closeModal();
                       var str = xhr.responseText;
                       var jsondata = eval("("+str+")");
                       // alert("str  "+str);
                       // alert("jsondata  "+jsondata);
                        wrapperFunc(jsondata);
                    }                
                }           
            </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="loadNewData()">
            <H3> POC for a Treemap in D3.js </h3>
             <form>
                    <br><br><br><br>
                    <label><input  type="radio" name="mode" value="size" checked> Clicks</label>    
            <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="ctr"> Ctr</label> 
            <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="searches"> Searches</label> 
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br><br>
                    <label>From</label>
                    <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
                    <label>to</label>
                    <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
                    <input type="button" class="btn" id="bt1" value="Fetch" onclick="loadNewData()">                
             </form> 
            <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
            <!-- <p><strong>Label</strong></p> -->
             <p><span id="value"></span></p>          
            </div>
            <div id="fade"></div>
            <div id="modal">
                <img id="loader" src="images/ajax-loader-Flower.gif" />
            </div>
            <script>

                function wrapperFunc(jsondata){

                    //alert("Inside wrapperFunc -- "+jsondata);
                    //var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
                   // var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
                    //width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    //height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                    var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
                    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 470 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                    var color = d3.scale.category20();
                    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
                                            .size([width, height])
                                            .sticky(true)
                                            .value(function(d) { return d.clicks;});    

                    d3.select("svg").remove();

                    var svg = d3.select("body")         
                                        .append("svg")
                                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right )
                                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                                        .append("g");

                    console.log("Inside root");
                    console.log(jsondata); 


            var rects = svg.datum(jsondata)
                    .selectAll("rect")
                    .data(treemap.nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .call(position);

            var texts = svg.selectAll("text") 
                    .data(treemap.nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .call(textPrint);

            //Tooltip and highlighting starts
            d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover",mouseover); 
            d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseout",mouseout); 
            //Tooltip and Highlighting ends

            //Transition of the Treemap.
            d3.selectAll("input").on("change",change);                          

            function change(){

                var value = this.value;
                if (this.value === "ctr") { value =  function(d) {return d.ctr;}}
                else if (this.value === "searches") { value = function(d) {return d.searches;}}
                else { value = function(d) {return d.clicks;}}    
                //alert(value);
                rects
                    .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
                    .transition()           
                    .duration(1500)
                    .call(position);    

                texts
                    .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
                    .transition()
                    .delay(1500)
                    .duration(500)
                    .call(textPrint);
                }//change

        function position(){
                this.attr("x", function(d) {return d.x;})
                    .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y;})
            .attr("width", function(d) {return d.dx;})
            .attr("height", function(d) {return d.dy;})
            .attr("stroke","white")
            .attr("fill", function(d) {   
                        if(d.children == null)
                         return color(d.parent.sub_group); // color(d.parent.name);
                                    else
                         return null;                       
                                        });
            }

        function textPrint(){
            this.attr("x",function(d) {return d.x + 3;})
            .attr("y",function(d) {return d.y + 10;})
            .attr("class","node")                   
            .text(function(d){
                    if(d.dx <= 10 || d.dy <= 10){ return ""; } //If the rect is too small do not display the text
                        else if (d.children == null){
                            var pxK = 6.6,txtLngth = (d.clientid).length,txtAccomadate = Math.round(d.dx/pxK);
                            if (txtAccomadate >= txtLngth)                                      
                                return d.clientid;                              
                            else 
                                                        return "";
                        // return (d.clientid).substr(0,txtAccomadate);
                                    }
                                    else
                            return null;
                                    });
                 }

        function mouseover(d){ 

            // The below code is used for highlighting the element (i.e. rect) on mouse hover 
            d3.select(this)
              .attr("fill", "orange");

            //Get this rects x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
            var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + (d.dx)/2;
            var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + (d.dy)/2;

            //Update the tooltip position and value
            d3.select("#tooltip")
            .style("left", xPosition + "px")
            .style("top", yPosition + "px")
            .select("#value")
            .text(d.parent.sub_group+"--"+d.clientid);

            //Show the tooltip
            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);         

        }

        function mouseout(d) {    

            d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
            if(d.children == null)
                return color(d.parent.sub_group);
            else
                return null;                        
            })          
            //Hide the tooltip
            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);      
        }           

        }//wrapperFunc

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped add jQuery-Ajax > options: async: false,

```
 function  initConfig() {
            console.log('initConfig:start');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "router.php", 
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                data: {"ajax_mode":"init-config"},
                success: function(msg){
                   window.storeobject = msg;
                   },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        }
```

regards
Andrzej Kmicic